# Windows 7 not working correctly after partition resize

Tags: linux, partition, windows

I resized the Windows partition from Linux in order to be able to install Elementary OS.
After resizing I tried booting to Windows, however it asks to boot normally or in recovery mode.
When I select normal, it returns to GRUB, and when I select Recovery Mode it tells me that an installed program isn't working.

I'd like to be able to use Windows 7, as certain websites won't work with Debian.

Partition layout after resize:

```
sda1 - bootloader (GRUB)
sda2 - windows partition
sda3 - windows recovery partition
sda4 - extended partition?
sda5 - linux-swap
sda6 - Debian 7.5
```

Comment: So you haven't installed Elementary OS yet? You just re-sized, and rebooted?

Comment: Yes.  Is this why Windows is messed up?  All files seem to be there.

Comment: Resizing a Windows partition should make Windows perform a disk-check upon boot; it shouldn't prevent Windows from booting. A screenshot would be helpful, as the partition info listed is very odd. You didn't move the partition when you re-sized it, right? I'm assuming you don't own a Windows installation disc.

Comment: I didn't move the partitions as far as I know.  Its the same layout as before, except that there is 18 GB of unallocated space now.  And no Windows recovery disk.  :(  I'll take a screenshot if I can.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not really sure that this is a correct place to ask such questions. But I assume that your partition numbering has changed when you created another partition for Linux therefore you'd need to change windows bootloader configuration.

The link provided says:

> Immediately Reboot Windows After Shrinking Partition
>
> After shrinking the Windows partition, you should reboot once (or
>   twice) into Windows prior to installing Ubuntu. This allows the
>   Windows system to automatically rescan the newly-resized partition and
>   write changes to its own bootloader configuration files.

If you didn't do that then you need to reconfigure your windows bootloader manually. Try to use this guide for example https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PpXCnZlIVVo

Comment: Where should I ask in that case?  Also, I have had Debian and Ubuntu installed before, I was resizing the partition to try eOS.

Comment: @wolf_adventures1909 This looks like Linux/Unix community to me. Did you resize your windows partition from Linux or from Windows? What was the layout before and what it is now?

Comment: Linux.  From eOS LiveCD.  As far as I can tell it is the same layout.

Comment: @wolf_adventures1909 Could you list your current layout in the question (sda1 - ?, sda5 - ? etc...). Did you follow any article when resizing a Windows partition from Linux, e.g. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowtoResizeWindowsPartitions ?

Comment: sda1 - bootloader (GRUB), sda2 - windows partition - sda3 -windows recovery partition - sda4 - extended partition? - sda5 - linux-swap - sda6 - Debian 7.5.

Comment: I have not installed anything.  there 18GB of unallocated space.